# How to Merge Conflicts by Selecting Lines from Both?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, merge-conflict-resolution, kdiff3

I'm learning the use of version control (with Tortoise HG) so this question might be very basic, but I can't figure out how to solve it.

Suppose Branch A has a text file with the following:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

Branch B has the same text file with:

```
A
B
3
4
E
F
```

When merging these two files with TortoiseHG, the merges are resolved with KDiff. Kdiff allows us to Select Lines from only one of the two. I want the Merged Code to contain lines from both like:

```
A
B
C
D
3
4
E
F
```

The order is not important. How do I solve the merge conflict in KDiff3 to get what I want?

This isn't an academic discussion. It is a simplified version of what is happening with code for a small Android application, where the XML files for Strings is edited in both Branches.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually quite simple, in kdiff3 you turn off the auto-advance, the button after the A B C set, then you go through the conflicts using the next conflict button, (immediately before A),  and on each conflict you toggle A or B or A then B or B then A to get the desired result - you can even manually edit the file in the bottom pane if necessary.

Comment: I don't know why auto-advance is default. It seems to confuse much more than it helps.

Comment: There are three options to choose from. You are likely to need a combination of B and C rather than A and B.

Comment: As @SteveKaye mentioned, I had to select first B and then C, rather than A and then B. (These 'ABC' are the windows in Kdiff3, rather than the Branches). After that, the merge worked.

Comment: Not sure how to edit at the bottom pane. Only lets me choose between A,B, and C. There is no option to manually edit.

Comment: Ah I figured it out. You have to choose 1 of the 3 before you are allowed to manually edit. Then, after choosing 1 of the 3 and manually editing, you can save the merge and move on to the next one.